# Can I define multiple callback methods depending on the call method?

Tags: rest-api, endpoints

He is my current custom API:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route('my-project/v1/form', '/get', array(
    'methods' => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
    'callback' => 'get_form'
  ));
});


add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route('my-project/v1/form', '/post', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'post_form'
  ));
});
```

Here is something I would like to write, but I'm not sure if it is possible.
What I'm sure is that this syntax i

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route('my-project/v1/', '/form',
array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'GET_form',
  ), array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'post_form',
  ), );
});
```

Comment: Yes, it's correct syntax. As you can read in [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/#parameters):  `$args` - Either an array of options for the endpoint, **or an array of arrays for multiple methods**.

Comment: @nmr keep comments for clarifying questions, and post answers as answers, afterall I can't upvote your comment and TTT can't mark it as the answer

Comment: @TomJNowell OK, it seemed to mee too insignificant to write as an answer.

Comment: Sometimes the answer is simple short and wellformed, don't let that discourage you from posting it!

Answer (score 3):

Check if your code looks like this because in the question you pass each method as separate function arguments (I have overlooked it earlier)

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {

    register_rest_route('my-project/v1/', '/form', 
        array(
            array('methods' => 'GET',
                 'callback' => 'GET_form',
            ), 
            array('methods' => 'POST',
                 'callback' => 'post_form'
            )
        ) 
    );
});
```

As you can read in [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/#parameters):

> ### Parameters #
>
> **$args** - (array) (Optional)
>
> Either an array of options for the endpoint, **or an array of arrays for multiple methods**.
>   Default value: array()

Comment: Thank you , however, it's not working. so far I need to define different roots for each methods.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what happens? And which parts don't work?

Comment: @TTT Are you sure you pass both methods as one array (you made a mistake during pasting), and not as two separate ones?